# Dagger 2 kotlin and generics

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to add multibinding to my fragment subcomponents, but I have problem with kotlin and generics. Basically I have 2 interfaces, 
One for modules:

`@Module
interface SbModule`

And one for subcomponents
`interface SbSubcomponent`
Then I have subcomponent builder

`interface SbBuilder<in A, out B> {
    fun module(module: A)
    fun build(): B
}`

My fragment subcomponent extends `SbSubcomponent` and its module extends `SbModule` obviously. then I have builder as:

`@dagger.Subcomponent.Builder
interface Builder: SbBuilder<Module, Subcomponent> {}`

And the problem starts in activity, lets omit map binding to make the problem more clear, I am biding my `Subcomponent.Builder` to `SbBuilder` but I have to specify the types exactly, so as follows:

`@Binds
abstract fun fragmentBuilder(impl: Fragment.Subcomponent.Builder): SbBuilder<Fragment.Subcomponent.Module, Fragment.Subcomponent>`

If I try with generics so `SbModule` and `SbSubcomponent`
then I am getting

`@Binds methods must have only one parameter whose type is assignable to the return type`

And after I specify the types exactly I cant inject it as generic ones.. however I can cast them to generic ones after injection and this is fine but thats not the point, I have been also messing with `@JvmSuppressWildcards` but no matter where I put them there is always problem. I must have missed something, but currently I have no idea what